# Dynamically binding controls with VB.NET/WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm starting programming in WPF and VB.NET right now. 
I was able to create a Combobox with the binding to a list of items of a dictionary.

I have a List of Dictionaries and I want to create a Combobox for each dictionary contained in such list.
So, if I have N Dictionaries, I want to show N comboboxes. Each of them should be bound to a dictionary.

Could someone give me some hints to perform this?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't provide any code or anything indicating that you have tried something. You haven't ever awarded an answer (-> I will never understand why some people do that; not showing any kind of appreciation to those helping them). By bearing in mind that everyone gets what he/she deserves, do you think that you deserve being helped?

Comment: How about a loop of some sort?